# Why is this layout not inflated to full width?

Tags: android, layout

I have a quite simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/b"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressD"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:progress="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberO"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressD"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And I inflate it like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends
    SherlockDialogFragment {

    static MyFragment newInstance() {
         MyFragment theDialog = new MyFragment();
         return theDialog;
        }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.dialog_show_progress_during_connection_test,
        container, false);
```

And this is how I show it:

```
 public void showIt(final Device device) {
    //first create the DialogFragment to show the progress
    theDialog = theDialog
        .newInstance();

    theDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
        "dialog");

    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
```

The fragment is rather narrow - about 1/3 of the screen width, even though I explicitly have "match_parent"

Curiously on an old Android phone with Android 2.1 it inflates almost to the width of the screen - while on all others running Android 4+ it is narrow.

I checked the value of container, it is null in all cases. (shouldn't it be the parent ?)

Could there be an issue with Sherlock?

I even set the width explicitly to 1000dp, but the new fragment remains narrow.
Also changing to LinearLayout does not help.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this?

The only way I got this to become wider was to set specific width like "500dp" in all places! within this xml file.
Many thanks!

Comment: how does your host activity look? how do you add the fragment?

Comment: the container in which you are replacing or adding the fragment may have small width

Comment: @ Rolf Smit  please see my edit - I just instantiate it, and the host activity fills the complete width

Comment: @Gaurav Vashisth the container is null

Comment: @user387184 i am not talking about the variable container, Please give the code when you are replacing/adding fragment to the activity

Comment: @ Gaurav Vashisth -> I added the code above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced that some attributes can override the layout_width-attribute. Try to remove layout_centerHorizontal, layout_centerVertical and scaleType from your RelativeLayout. As far as I can see, they fill no purpose either way.

Comment: Then why made it an answer ?